# Excel VBA to copy -> muliple paste and rename a windows file from an excel column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not that smart when it comes to programming. Please bear with me.

I have an image.pdf file in a source location `c:\Source`. I want to create a copy of this file and rename it in a different location under a different name. But the question is not over it.

I want to perform this paste operation for let's say hundred times and rename all the files based on an Excel column. Every day the range expands or shrinks.

For Example

> Source File Name - Image.Jpg
>   Source Location - C:\Source\
>   Destination File Name - D:\Destination\
>   Destination File Names -
>
> Alpha.Jpg
>   Beta.Jpg
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Zebra.Jpg

Could you please provide me with a code and sample Excel file to perform this by just entering the source and destination file names and locations?

Please help me out as I've been spending a lot of time in doing this every day. Please let me know if you need a sample Excel sheet for reference.

Comment: We don't supply example code on SO unless you have tried it yourself and are having problems with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will have to add the reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. You do it under "Tools" -> "References"

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCopies(ByVal destPath As String, ByVal templateFullPathName As String)

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim aName As Variant
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim myDest As String
Dim lastRow As Long, iCell As Long

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' Find last row in column A
lastRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through cells from last row to 2nd row (if 1st row is header)
For iCell = lastRow To 2 Step -1

    aName = Cells(iCell, 2).Value

    myDest = destPath & "\" & "Copy of " & aName & ".pdf"

    fso.CopyFile _
       Source:=templateFullPathName, _
       Destination:=myDest

Next iCell

If Not (fso Is Nothing) Then Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


Sub UseThisToCallProcedure()
Call CreateCopies("D:\Destination\", "C:\Source\FILETOCOPY.pdf")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to reply back.